# Display value in input - xslt

Tags: xslt

Xml

```
<PARAMETER id='threshold' Value='1000' />
```

How to display the value of the above PARAMETER (Threshold) in the input?

Xslt

```
 <xsl:when test="@id = 'threshold'">
<td>
<input type="text" id="txtthreshold" value=’@Value‘>
</input>
</td>
</xsl:when>
```

Also I would want to allow the user to change the value of the input and bring it back to the application(windows.vbnet). Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post your complete XML and XSLT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For displaying the value of an XPath expression within an attribute defined as a attr_name="xpath_expression", the XPath expression must be surrounded by curly brackets ({, }).

In your case,

```
<input type="text" id="txtthreshold" value="{@Value}"></input>
```

Another way of doing that is using the <xsl:attribute> XSLT element:

```
<input type="text" id="txtthresold">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Value" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

Comment: Many thanks Pablo Pozo for your help. I have now managed to display values in text box. could you also suggest how to capture the value entered by the user on a button click? the modified value has to be passed to a windows application.

Comment: You cannot do that with XSLT. You have to use a different language (probably JavaScript, VBScript, depending with which language you are working). The standard thing would be using and onclick="" attribute in the input and putting there the code which is going to be used to pass the value to the application. I cannot help you more without knowing exactly what you are doing. Sorry.